# Agregar filas a archivo Excel con Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lo siento, no se mucho sobre pandas y lo que ahora quiero lograr es agregar una fila a mi archivo Excel (xlsx), he intentado con el metodo `append` de **pandas** pero no se agrega

```
fileEst = pd.read_excel('mate2.xlsx)
fileEst .append(
    pd.Series(['holaaaaas']),
    ignore_index=True
    )
```

Cómo puedo agregar una fila?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomendaría que en ves de usar `pandas` uses la librería llamada `openpyxl`.

Para poderla usar, primero tienes que instalara con `pip` desde la terminal, con el siguiente comando:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Luego de hacer eso, ya podras trabajar con ella en cualquier script. Te dejo un ccódigo de ejemplo que escribe información en las celdas de un excel y al final lo guarda con el nombre y ruta que desees:

```
#Importación de librerias
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# Hacer el archivo de trabajo activo
ws = wb.active

# La información la puedes asignar directamente a las celdas, en este caso el 42 a la celda A1
ws['A1'] = 42

# Los regustros tamlbien se pueden anexar con "append" en forma de lista
ws.append(["holaas", "hola2", "HOLA MUNDO"])

# Tipo de dato en python automaticamente va a ser convertido para leer en excel, en este caso la fecha de hoy
import datetime
ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()

# Guardar el archivo en cualquier ruta, si no la especificas detalladamente la pondra en la carpeta donde estas corriendo este programa
wb.save("mate3.xlsx")
```

La salida es como se ve a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Saludos!

Comment: Gracias, en caso de querer guardar un dato sin especificar el lugar, osea que automáticamente se añada al final de una columna o fila, como lo haría?

Comment: Con el uso de un "for" puedes iterar sobre las filas que tengas, y en cuanto a las columnas, como puedes observar, se irán añadiendo encoladas con la propia función "append" . Te dejo un recurso a documentación donde puedes consultar sobre el ejemplo que comentas https://j2logo.com/python/crear-archivo-excel-en-python-con-openpyxl/#openpyxl-escribir-celda

Comment: lo siento me había olvidado de aceptar la respuesta, gracias